# how to write Humble reminder email

Tags: email

how to ask sorry for the late reminder in official email

Ex:
I'm sorry for sending you a late remainder

Is this correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That certainly works. A slightly more formal variation is `I apologize for the late reminder`, which is what I personally choose to use most of the time, and may be what you should use if the email isn't a casual one.